# facebook multi friend selector not showing in IE8

Tags: facebook

In my application user can invite friend form facebook, for this i use facebook multi friend selector. User can select facebook friend and when click on invite friend button it show multi friend selector in a modal window for this exclude rest of user, but it's not showing in IE8. When I remove exclude_ids parameter in  multi friend selector then it showing in IE8 with all friend.In the other browser it work perfectly.

Below is the fbml code which is I am using

```
<fb:serverfbml width="615" >
<script type="text/fbml">
<fb:request-form action="http://example.com/invitefriends.html"
method="post"
target="_top"
invite="true"
type="invite"
content=" content text. <fb:req-choice url='<? echo JURI::base(); ?>home/facebook/<? echo base64_encode($user->get('email')); ?>' label=Bloom.com />">">
<fb:multi-friend-selector showborder="true"
bypass="cancel"
rows=3
cols=3
email_invite="false"
import_external_friends="false"
exclude_ids="<? echo $exclude_ids; ?>"

actiontext="Invite your friend from facebook" />
</fb:request-form>
</script>
</fb:serverfbml>
```

Anyone have any solution for this.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

try to define fbml in html tag:

```
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well.  The solution I found was to add an extra fb:multi-friend-selector tag just before the fbml:

```
<!-- stupid ie fix -->
<fb:multi-friend-selector />
<!-- end stupid ie fix -->

<fb:serverfbml width="625">...etc.
```

I don't know why it worked, but it did.